# plsql comparing structure of tables in 2 different database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a task of comparing structure of tables between 2 different databases. If there is a column missing I have to report the missing column and its tables.

Simple minus query will not return. As I am very new to pl sql programming, I am not getting any ideas.

can someone please help me with this?

```
Table 1:
Columns 
ABC
DEF
GHI

Table2:
ABC
DEF 
GHI
JKL
```

Here is an additional column. If this has to be reported, how do I do it.

PFB my simple proc:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_EU_TABLE_COMPARE (
R_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
SRC_SCHEMA_NAME         IN VARCHAR2,
TGT_SCHEMA_NAME         IN VARCHAR2
)

IS 


CNT3 NUMBER;
SQL_TEXT3 VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

--SRC_SCHEMA_NAME      := UPPER(SRC_SCHEMA_NAME);
--TGT_SCHEMA_NAME      := UPPER(TGT_SCHEMA_NAME);


SQL_TEXT3:='SELECT * FROM 
((SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''%EU%'' AND OWNER ='''||SRC_SCHEMA_NAME||'''
        MINUS
        SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%EU%''AND OWNER ='''||TGT_SCHEMA_NAME||''')
        UNION
        (SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%EU%''AND OWNER ='''||TGT_SCHEMA_NAME||'''
        MINUS
        SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''%EU%'' AND OWNER ='''||SRC_SCHEMA_NAME||'''))';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT3 INTO CNT3;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CNT3);

END;
```

Comment: There are quite a few options without writing your own code. SQL Developer compare schema objects for example. 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_compare_schemas.htm

Answer (score 1):

First of all, developer IDEs (PL/SQL Developer, Oracle SQL Developer) have tools for schema comparison.
Also, you are asking about two databases, but in your code you compare two **schemas** in the same database. Make sure you understand the difference.
And the last thing, you don't need to use execute immediate here. Here the script for SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create table table1 (
  abc number,
  def number,
  ghi number);

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (
  abc number,
  def number,
  ghi number,
  jkl number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure compare_tables is
begin
  for i in (select column_name 
              from all_tab_columns
             where table_name = 'TABLE2'
             minus
            select column_name 
              from all_tab_columns
             where table_name = 'TABLE1') loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.column_name);         
  end loop;
end;
/

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Columns of table2 not presented in table1:');
  compare_tables;
end;
/

Columns of table2 not presented in table1:
JKL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This code almost equal to yours, so if it doesn't work, try to compare tables manually or create a reproduceble example.